# Set up a counter for a JavaScript timer loop based on number of images

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

What I would like to do is set each BannerImg element to display: none one at a time using a timer setup. Then, once I have looped through all BannerImg elements, I want to reset them to display: block. It's basically like a image rotator that I'm trying to make...but right now, I'm not sure how to target each BannerImg element one at a time--I am targeting them all at once, which is not what I want to do.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var BannerCount = $('BannerImg').length;

        var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {

           $('.BannerImg').toggleClass("HideBannerImg"); 

          }, 2000);

    });

}(jQuery));
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand your questions.. Can you elaborate..

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand what you just said....but if you're trying to loop through something and 'target' each one individually, you just use a loop. Each "pass through" is the individual 'target.' Use the array.length property as your max condition, then it'll stop once it hits the end of the loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`.eq(index)`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/). You'll probably want to cache your collection to make it faster:

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var $banners = $('.BannerImg'); 
        var index = 0;
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
           $banners.eq(index).toggleClass("HideBannerImg");
           index++;
           // Check to see if we've hit the end of the collection
           // If so, stop the interval.
           if (index === $banners.length) {
               clearInterval(intervalID);
           }
        }, 2000);
    });    
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of guessing you want something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/8u1fnkag/) (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
setInterval(function () {
    if ($('.BannerImg').last().hasClass('HideBannerImg')) {
        $('.HideBannerImg').first().removeClass('HideBannerImg');
    } else {
        $('.BannerImg').not('.HideBannerImg').first().addClass('HideBannerImg');
    }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var iterator = 0;
        var BannerCount = $('BannerImg').length;
        var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
            $('.BannerImg').eq(iterator).toggleClass("HideBannerImg");
            iterator += 1;
            if (iterator === BannerCount.length - 1) {
                clearInterval(intervalID);
                $('.BannerImg').removeClass("HideBannerImg");
            }
        }, 2000);
    });
}(jQuery));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this recursive function

```
var images = $('.BannerImg').each();

var hideImage = function(index){
    images[index].toggleClass("HideBannerImg"); 
    if(index < images.length-1)
    setTimeout(function(){
        hideImage(index++);
    }, 2000);
}

hideImage(0);
```

Comment: no need to use `.each()`. `$('.BannerImg')` gives you all image element.

Comment: `images[index]` will return an HTMLElement, not a jQuery object, so `toggleClass` will not be available. Have you tested this?

Comment: Also, `.each` requires a function to be passed in. That's not the proper use of that function.

Answer (score 0):

After calling `$('.BannerImg')` you need to use jQuery's [each](https://api.jquery.com/each/) to loop over each of the elements it selected.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.BannerImg').each(function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var intervalID = window.setInterval(function() {
        $this.toggleClass("HideBannerImg");
      }, 2000);
    });
  });

}(jQuery));
```

Just note that this will toggle on and off over and over until you clear the interval.

Comment: I think this is one the right track but it still sets each BannerImg element to display: none or display: block all at once instead of one at a time...

Comment: Just edited, run the setInterval within the each loop.